# Как сохранить данные с первого запуска, чтобы во втором запуске их можно было использовать?

Tags: python, c++, математика, олимпиада

Есть простая задача, которая запускается два раза, причем входные данные при втором запуске зависят от того, что вывело решение при первом запуске.

Описание задачи:
Есть последовательность чисел от 1 до n, причем все числа встречаются один раз. Два числа в этой последовательности пропущены, их надо вывести при втором запуске (это вся задача...)

**Первый запуск:**

Входные данные:

1. Вводится слово "first";
2. Затем следуют два числа (длина последовательности и длина первой части последовательности);
3. Числа из первой части последовательности, которые надо запомнить.

Выходные данные:

1. Выводится памятка, которая подается во второй строке второго запуска (Памятка может быть любой, главное из нее получить необходимую информацию)

**Второй запуск:**

Входные данные:

1. Вводится слово "second";
2. Затем вводится памятка ?? (вот это как раз таки вся сложность задачи);
3. Затем следуют два числа (длина последовательности и длина второй части последовательности);
4. Вторая часть последовательности.

Выходные данные:

1. Два пропущенных числа этой последовательности

[image: Пример запуска программы.]

Пробовал сохранять в файл, но тесты не проходят (олимпиадная задача):

````
if order == 'first':
    f = open('text.txt', 'w')
    input()
    memo = ' '.join(input().split())
    f.write(memo)
    print(memo)
    f.close()
else:
    f = open('text.txt')
    left = f.read()
    print(left)
    left = set(map(int, left.split()))
    n = int(input().split()[0])
    right = set(map(int, input().split()))
    allNumbers = set(range(1, n + 1))
    print(*(allNumbers - left - right))
    f.close()```
````

Comment: А при чем тут c++?

Comment: Прочтите пример ещё раз. Неужели не очевидно зачем нужна памятка?

Comment: @Павел , если есть способ решения на c++, то можно предлагать (просто я его совсем немного понимаю, а решать задачу можно на любом яп)

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy , я понимаю зачем нужна памятка, просто непонятно, как ее можно перекинуть с одного запуска на второй, вот это мне не ясно

Comment: Дайте URL... Памятка — то, что вывели, потом вам подается как входные данные. Никакой файл не нужен...

Comment: @Harry https://tsweb.ru/olymp/2022-2023/2022-selection-a-j.pdf (задача C)

Comment: @Harry, "памятка должна иметь длину от 0 до 1000 символов и состоять из символов с ASCII-кодами от 32 до 126.". Вот истинная суть задачи!

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy Как обычно, когда автор вопроса пишет свою трактовку задачи, а не условие... Еще играет немалую роль предельное значение n. И, как мне кажется, очень важно, что отсутствующие числа — во второй части последовательности.

Comment: @Harry, где отсутствующие числа - не важно. Глаша разобрала числа в три кучки любым образом, показала первую, показала вторую. Что в третьей (размера два)? Это "ксорная" задача для которой надо придумать компактное хранение статуса. Задача хорошая.

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy Да, с местом отсутствия — у меня возникла неудачная идея. Сейчас склоняюсь к тому, что хранения суммы и суммы квадратов достаточно. Нет? Еще проще — произведения, но тогда нужна длинная арифметика.

Comment: ТС, почитайте https://habr.com/ru/company/vdsina/blog/538298/ . Что-нибудь в голову придет. Не пытайтесь сохранять файлы - не выйдет. Придумывайте как в памятку упаковать информацию о тысячах чисел.

Comment: @Harry, произведения убьют производительность (или можно разлагать на простые :). Многочлены - можно. Ещё битовые операции.

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy , спасибо большое! Сейчас попробую разобраться

Answer (score 4, accepted):

В качестве **эксперимента**<sup>*</sup>, что достаточно выводить как промежуточные данные сумму и сумму квадратов, для чего 1000 символов за глаза...

```
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <random>

using namespace std;

default_random_engine rgen{random_device{}()};

constexpr long long N = 300000;

pair<long long,long long> first(vector<int>::iterator b, vector<int>::iterator e)
{
    pair<long long,long long> p{0,0};
    for(auto it = b; it != e; ++it)
    {
        long long i = *it;
        p.first  += i;
        p.second += i*i;
    }
    return p;
}

pair<long long,long long> second(vector<int>::iterator b, vector<int>::iterator e,
                                 long long s, long long q)
{
    for(auto it = b; it != e; ++it)
    {
        long long i = *it;
        s += i;
        q += i*i;
    }
    long long n = N*(N+1)/2 - s;
    long long m = N*(N+1)*(1+2*N)/6 - q;
    long long x = round((n+sqrt(2*m-n*n))/2);
    long long y = n - x;
    return make_pair(x,y);
}

int main(int argc, char * argv[])
{
    vector<int> v(N);
    for(int i = 0; i < N; ++i) v[i] = i+1;
    shuffle(v.begin(),v.end(),rgen);
    long long div = N/2 + uniform_int_distribution<>(-N/4,N/4)(rgen);
    auto [s,q] = first(v.begin(),v.begin()+div);
    auto [x,y] = second(v.begin()+div,next(v.end(),-2),s,q);

    long long a = *next(v.end(),-2), b = *next(v.end(),-1);

    cout << x << "  " << y << "  vs  " << a << "  " << b << endl;
}
```

<sup>*</sup> Это не решение поставленной задачи, а намек на ее решение.

P.S. Есть у меня подозрение, что именно это и имелось в виду, потому как при подсчете суммы квадратов по приведенной формуле получается почти заполненный `long long` :)

Comment: Спасибо огромное! У меня получилось решить)

Comment: Спасибо здесь имеет вид щелчка мышкой на треугольнике вверх слева от ответа; большое спасибо — щелчок на "птичке" там же... :)